# Population of rabbits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, word-problem

The rate of increase of rabbits on Hare island varies directly with the number of rabbits present at any time. If the initial population is $P_0$ and the population doubles in $Td$ days, how long in terms of $Td$, will the population take to triple?

Comment: Google Lotka-Volterra, you'll find tons of examples like this. Also, please read some other questions so you know how to structure your question, and what kind of questions can be asked. This is not good format for SE.

Comment: This is also not your first post you should at least use Mathjax for your variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: "Depends directly" would normally imply $P'(t)=P(t)$, but I think they mean "is proportional to the amout of rabbit", which implies $$P'(t)=kP(t)$$, where $P(t)$ is the population after time $t$. Solve this ODE to find $P(t)=c_0e^{kt}$. Now use your initial data $P(t=0)=P_0$ and your datapoint $P(t=t_d)=2P_0$ to determin $c_0$ and $k$.

EDIT: Finding $c_0$ and $k$.

From your initial data, you can directly conclude that $c_0=P_0$. If you use this for the second data point, we get:

$$2P_0=P_0e^{kt_d}$$
$$\ln2=kt_d$$
$$k=\frac{\ln2}{t_d}$$

Hence, $P(t)=P_0e^{\ln2 \frac{t}{t_d}}=P_0e^{\ln(2^{t/t_d})}=P_0e^{t/t_d}$

In order to find the time to triple $t_3$

$$P(t=t_3)=3P_0=P_02^{t_3/t_d}$$

$$t_3=t_d\cdot \frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(2)}$$

Comment: I ended up with t = ln3/ln2 days, is that right?

Comment: What is $t_d$ in your problem?

Comment: it's just says that it is the amount of time it takes for the population to double.

Comment: edited my answer.